# Apache mod_headers regex for multiple cookies?

Tags: regex, apache, cookies, mod-headers, samesite

I'm using the following code to edit set the SameSite attribute for specific cookies:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(login_session.*)$ $1;SameSite=Strict
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(different_cookie.*)$ $1;SameSite=Strict
</IfModule>
```

This works, BUT is there a way to combine the two rules into a one-liner?
I know how to set this to ALL cookies or to exclude specific cookies, but is there a way to specifiy 2 or more cookies in a one-line regex? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always edit Set-Cookie ^((login|different)_session.*)$ $1;SameSite=Strict
</IfModule>
```